# Traversing a tree into an array

Tags: java, tree, traversal, preorder

I'm supposed to traverse a Binary Seach Tree as preorder, inorder and postorder and insert the values into an Object[] in Java. I honestly have no clue how to do this and I need some advice.

My function:

```
public Object[] traversePreOrder()
```

All I need are basically some ideas or hints on how to complete this task.
If I traverse a tree as preorder Object[0] is obviously the value of the root. Then I continue in the left tree and insert the most left values in my array.
Next I insert the right child of the most left node and continue with the parent of both nodes if the right node has no children.

But my method can't remember which values have already been checked and inserted. I also thought of traversing in postorder, putting each element onto an stack and push each element onto my array, but I've got limits to my knowledge on how to implement this.

Help!

Here's what is in my opinion already correct:

```
@Override
public Object[] traversePreOrder() {
    Object[] preOrderArray = new Object[elements];
    if (elements == 0) {
        return preOrderArray;
    }



    return preOrderArray;

}
```

The gap has to be filled obviously.

Additionally I have as basic methods and constructors:

```
BinarySearchTreeNode(T value, BinarySearchTreeNode<T> left,
        BinarySearchTreeNode<T> right) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

BinarySearchTreeNode(T value) {
    this(value, null, null);
}

BinarySearchTreeNode<T> getLeft() {
    return left;
}

void setLeft(BinarySearchTreeNode<T> left) {
    this.left = left;
}

BinarySearchTreeNode<T> getRight() {
    return right;
}

void setRight(BinarySearchTreeNode<T> right) {
    this.right = right;
}

T getValue() {
    return value;
}

void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: Use a queue, then convert it to an array.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Comment: It's a non-mandatory assignment. I'm doing it to be prepared for my exams.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Implementations

Comment: Can we see your method at least?

Comment: Show us the code please.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal case for using recursion. Create a method

```
List<BinarySearchTreeNode> traverse(BinarySearchTreeNode n) {
    // traversal code
}
```

where the traversal code traverses the left child and the right child if any, and

- for preorder traversal, concatenates the value, left child's result and the right child's result;
- for inorder traversal, concatenates the left child's result, the value, and the right child's result;
- for postorder traversal, concatenates the left child's result, the right child's result and the value.

Call `traverse` for the root and convert the result into an `Object[]`.

Comment: Can you have the return type for this recursive method be a List? Seems like every time it gets called it's going to try to return a separate list? Maybe I'm looking at this wrong...

Comment: Sure it would return a separate list each time - just combine them into a list of your own. Your solution will work as well and in fact be a log n-factor faster because you're not copying lists around, but you rely on the side effect of a recursive function, which is a lot less obvious to reason about.

Comment: @Pulz if you like it, do consider upvoting

Answer (score 0):

As Arend mentioned above, this is the general idea. I'm not sure if you can have it return a list each time, but you might be able to. However, if that implementation doesn't work you could try something like this just to see if everything else is working:

```
private List nodeValues = new ArrayList();

public void traversePreRecursive(BinarySearchTreeNode node) 
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        nodeValues.add(node.getValue());
        traversePreRecursive(node.getLeft());
        traversePreRecursive(node.getRight());
    }
}
```