# Recursive Tree Traversal Method With Return Type Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-tree, traversal

Is there a way to recursively traverse a tree and return an array that is scoped to that recursive method?

So I recently answered someone else's question on this topic. That question can be found here: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819177/traversing-a-tree-into-an-array). My solution uses an array outside of the scope of the recursion, and therefore the method cannot (or at least probably should not) return the array. However, is there a way to write a recursive method for traversing trees such that it returns an array? Even writing an initial method that calls the recursive one would be fine, but I can't think of a good way to do this.

Here's the code that I suggested before:

```
private List nodeValues = new ArrayList();

public void traversePreRecursive(BinarySearchTreeNode node) 
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        nodeValues.add(node.getValue());
        traversePreRecursive(node.getLeft());
        traversePreRecursive(node.getRight());
    }
}
```

As you can see the `ArrayList` is outside of the scope of the recursion - And therefore returning it doesn't make a lot of sense. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It would be good to have a java tag on this question

Comment: Added. Wasn't sure if it would be a help or hindrance, many languages could have a similar issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static List traversePreRecursive(Node node) {
    if (node == null) return new ArrayList();

    List nodeValues = new ArrayList();
    nodeValues.add(node.getValue());
    nodeValues.addAll(traversePreRecursive(node.getLeft()));
    nodeValues.addAll(traversePreRecursive(node.getRight()));

    return nodeValues;
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I guess I wasn't perfectly clear about this. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with just a plain array rather than an ArrayList as well.

Comment: Also, while this will work, I get the sense that this is going to be much less efficient than using an array outside of the scope of the recurions...

Comment: I doubt it would be much more efficient to use an array. The basic problem is knowing how many elements you're going to add to the array. If you knew that then you could presize the array list too, and gain the same benefits. The array list is a rather simple wrapper around an array that manages the expansion of the array for you, so without knowing the size of the array in advanced you'd end up writing this code yourself, and that would probably be less efficient than the standard array list implementation.

Comment: Right, I know how ArrayList is built. Maybe I'm just being naive, but wouldn't calling addAll cause it to have to re-write to the list each element in the list so far after each return of traversePreRecursive? So instead of an O(n) operation you now have an O(n^2) operation?

Comment: You could be forgiven for thinking so, but java is highly optimised for this type of operation. Under the covers the `addAll()` method defers to a native implementation of `arrayCopy()` on the `System` object, which is implemented in the fastest method possible (given the constraints of the platform/jvm-implementation) -- typically it's using blitters and memory-mapping. Which means that the operation involves allocating memory and block-copying the data from each list into a single block of memory in a single operation per list.

Comment: Of course, if the tree were massive, and the data at each node were massive, you'd probably want to count the nodes in your subtree before running your query. You would use the count to initialize each list with enough elements to hold the results without resizing, then you only have to worry about the performance of the copy, which is probably constrained by memory architecture on your given platform. When you're running into those constraints, you're pretty optimal.

Comment: Hey, I'm still not sure how this would be done with just a basic array, even if you knew how many nodes there were going in. That said, this is probably the best implementation anyway, so I've accepted it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative, but it involves two passes over the tree. You would only employ this alternative if the array operations in my first answer were giving you grief. This approach starts by providing an index for each of the nodes (the `index()` method) -- basically working out which element of the array a node should occupy before we actually create the array. This also gives me a count of nodes (`size`). I then allocate an array (`list`) big enough to hold all the nodes and pass it into a method (`addToList`) that copies the node-references into the previously identified element in the array.

```
public static List<Node> getNodes(Node a) {
    int size = index(a, 0);
    List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>(size);
    addToList(a, list);
    return list;
}

private static int index(Node node, int index) {
    if (node == null) return index;

    node.setIndex(index);
    int iLeft = index(node.getLeft(), index++);
    int iRight = index(node.getRight(), iLeft++);

    return iRight + 1;
}

private static void addToList(Node node, List<Node> list) {
    if(node == null) return;
    list.add(node.getIndex(), node);
    addToList(node.getLeft(), list);
    addToList(node.getRight(), list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c you can have static function variables,(Ie, adding a value to a list in one iteration of a function means that that value will be in the list in the next iteration--if the list is static) but using them isn't the best (most optimal) solution for the problem you are suggesting. So, I think you are searching for static variables, but this isn't an appropriate case to use them.