# Travel in PreOrder on a BinTree in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi i was given a task to implement a function that iterate over a bin tree and 
return all its value in pre order. the code is as below:

```
interface BinTree {
    root: number;
    left?: BinTree;
    right?: BinTree;
};
const TreePreArray =(t:BinTree):number[] => {
    let list = new Array<number>();
    if (t==undefined) {return list }
    else {
        list.push(t.root)
        list.concat(TreePreArray(t.left))
        list.concat(TreePreArray(t.right))
    }
    return list
}
let bn : BinTree = {
    root: 1,
    left: { root: 2 },
    right: { root: 3 }
}
console.log((TreePreArray(bn)));
```

but the output is only [1] and not [1,2,3] I have copied the idea from this link
[Recursive Tree Traversal Method With Return Type Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996314/recursive-tree-traversal-method-with-return-type-array) and implemented it in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push or to use the result of `concat`. Becuase of the missing assignment of the result of `concat`, you miss the result of traveling the branches.

Either

```
list = list.concat(TreePreArray(t.left))
list = list.concat(TreePreArray(t.right))
```

or

```
list.push(...TreePreArray(t.left))
list.push(...TreePreArray(t.right))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really good usecase for iterators:

```
 function* leftFirst({left, right, root} : BinTree) {
  yield root; 
  if(left) yield* leftFirst(left); 
  if(right) yield* leftFirst(right); 
 }
```

To then get an array just do:

```
 [...leftFirst(someTree)]
```